# Is it possible to use the result from a renderPlot without shiny session?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I've created a dashboard which shows a plot, based on data that is updated every 8 hours. This data is updated via a cron-jobbed Python script, so R/shiny is only for plotting/dashboarding purposes. The plot is created via a couple of `reactive` functions, and finally a `renderPlot`. Is it possible to call or import these reactive functions without a shiny context, so that I can create the plot, without running the dashboard?

The final goal is to create the plot and save/send it every time the data is updated from Python, without having duplicate R code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do this would be via creating a package.

For example, if you build an app through the [`{golem}`](https://github.com/ThinkR-open/golem) framework, you can use the inner "business" functions outside of the app.

So the idea would be to:

- Build the function that takes input and generate the plot
- Use this function inside your renderPlot.

For example :

In plots.R

```r
my_plot <- function(dataset){
  ggplot(dataset, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + 
    geom_point()
}
```

Then you can reuse this in an app:

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- function(request){
  plotOutput("plot")
}

server <- function(input, output, session){

  r <- reactiveValues()

  observe({
    r$data <- iris
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    my_plot(r$data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The idea here is that if you have built everything as a package (for example named "`{myapp}`", you'll be able to access `myapp::my_plot()` outside of a shiny context.

So when launching the cron, you can add something like `R -e 'myapp::my_plot(dataset)'`.

Comment: Interesting. I never heard of `{golem}`. Can this also work without it, if you for example put the `my_plot` function in a different R file (i.e. `functions.R`, and have another script (`cron.R`) source the first file, and execution the `my_plot` function?

Comment: I sure will if you `source()` the file with the function. I'd advice against that though as the package allows you to bundle a more robust version of this function (with tests, dependencies management, documentation...). If you have a file with one function, you're just one `DESCRIPTION` file away from building a package :)